# Conditional Formatting Cells from a table in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to have a cell check values of two cells to the left of it, compare them to a table elsewhere in the sheet, and give me a specific value. I've scoured the Internet for a solution, to no avail. [An example of what I'm working on.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I4eLJvTgNr8H65skugUI-H1Gp4CbCyCvyGiu0EhCdMc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you make the sheet public to reference?

Comment: Sorry about that, the link should work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as a custom function.

```
function attackPower(level,basePower) 
{
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sht=ss.getActiveSheet();
    var rng=sht.getRange('F5:M25');
    var rngA=rng.getValues();
    var bpwrrng=sht.getRange('F3:M3');
    var bpwrrngA=bpwrrng.getValues();
    var bpwridx=bpwrrngA[0].indexOf(basePower);
    var r=rngA[level][bpwridx];
    return r;
}
```

Comment: It would be faster if you just created rngA by hand. It's just the values at F5:M25 and the same with bpwrrngA is the values at F3:M3.

Comment: Thank you for the help, kind person! What I found out is that this function doesn't like to work when I try entering it into a merged cell, but works fine if I merge the cells after I enter the function.